# Uploading file without copying content to root folder .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm playing with Azure Blob Storage and I'm wondering if I can optimize this code a bit.

As you can see I'm creating folder and then uploading content to that folder before sending to Azure Storage and upon competition I'm deleting that folder it seems a bit redundant to be fair.

Now, I'm wondering if I can skip this few steps and just upload stream to azure without copying first to root folder?

Here is the code:

```
   public async Task UploadBlobFile(IFormFile file, BlobMetadata metadata,  string containerName)
    {
        var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders
        {
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            ContentLanguage = "hr-HR",
        };

        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var rootFolder = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "upload");

                if (!Directory.Exists(rootFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(rootFolder);
                }

                // create folder if doesnt exists
                var filePath = Path.Combine(rootFolder, file.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {

                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

                    // set cursor to the beginning of the stream.
                    stream.Position = 0;

                    var metadataProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { MetadataValues.Id, metadata.Id },
                        { MetadataValues.Name, metadata.Name },
                        { MetadataValues.UniqueName, metadata.UniqueName }
                    };

                    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);

                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, headers, metadataProperties);

                }

                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `file`? That's gonna be key to answering your question. It *appears* it's something stream-based, so have you tried `blobClient.UploadAsync(file, headers, metadataProperties)`?

Comment: Also note that as written, your `try`/`catch` serves no purpose and you should either remove it or do something meaningful in the catch block. You should also never `throw ex;` as it destroys the stacktrace, use `throw;` instead to re-throw the exception. But if you're just gonna catch to re-throw and do nothing else (ie log) then it's "the same" as not having the try/catch in the first place

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thank you. I updated code sample

Comment: You can create a folder in Storage and directly upload your files there.

Comment: [`IFormFile.OpenReadStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-3.1) will return a `Stream` that you can use directly with `blobClient.UploadAsync`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Ok, post it as answer in example and i ll upvote and accept. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As fellow **Bradley Uffner** and **pinkfloydx33** pointed out, code above can be optimized like this

```
public async Task UploadBlobFile(IFormFile file, BlobMetadata metadata,  string containerName)
{
    var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders
    {
        ContentType = "application/pdf",
        ContentLanguage = "hr-HR",
    };

    if (file.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            // set cursor to the beginning of the stream.
            stream.Position = 0;
            var metadataProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { MetadataValues.Id, metadata.Id },
                { MetadataValues.Name, metadata.Name },
                { MetadataValues.UniqueName, metadata.UniqueName }
            };

            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, headers, metadataProperties);

        }
    }
}
```